# Is f1-micro VM machine type forever free?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I try to create an f1-micro package, below the month fees appears this message:

Your first 720 hours of f1-micro instance usage are free this month.

Currently is November, which has 30 days. 720 divided by 30 is 24 hours. It appears as the f1-micro package is for free the whole month.

I tried looking up for some information online, but I wasn't able to find any helpful information. It looks like the f1-micro is always free for the first month. Now, the question is, if the f1-micro will be for free even after this period. Have anyone some experience with this?

Comment: Googling "Google free tier" should bring you to https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier. Look in particular at the "Always Free" section.

Comment: @robsiemb wrote a good answer. In addition, review pricing in detail. For small instance types like f1-micro your costs are not the compute instance, it is the bandwidth, storage, snapshots, images, etc. An f1-micro is good for learning, but do not expect too much. Your iPhone has more power.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

UPDATE（Aug, 2021）: From Augest 1st, 2021, the Free Tier F1-micro VM is changing to the E2-micro VM as the VM to use for free. On August 1, 2021, E2-micro Free Tier will be introduced. Follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#before-you-begin) to change your machine type to E2-micro to avoid incurring charges for continuing to use F1-micro after August 31, 2021.

---

Yes, a single `f1-micro` instance falls within the "[Always Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits)" and will be free for the entire month (the number of hours adjusts per month), as long as it is in one of the allowed regions (As of this writing, that means `us-west1`, `us-central1`, or `us-east1`).  Also note that the disk image for this instance will also be free, as long as it is 30GB or less and not SSD.

This program is not limited to the current month -- it renews every month (though of course the # of hours are slightly different each month).  At least, until Google changes the terms of the program :)

Additionally, when GCP starts charging for external IP addresses at the beginning of 2020, a single external IP address, as long as it is in use, will also be free for the entire month.

It is important to note that the always free tier is not set up as "1 instance" it is set up as a number of instance hours (or instance months, or ip-address-months).  So, you could run 3 instances concurrently for a third of a month as well (as long as they each only had no more than a 30GB disk attached each -- the limit of total disk usage is 30GB-months).

Finally, while some services (such as certain click to deploy Cloud Platform marketplace solutions) directly consume GCE resources and therefore are able to benefit from the GCE free tier, others do not, even though they specify instance types.  For example, a micro Cloud SQL instance will not be within the free tier.  GKE also cannot operate fully in free tier, as Google no longer supports `f1-micro` node pools for GKE.

Comment: Note: Starting January 1, 2020, GCP will charge for VM instance external IP addresses. However, under the GCP Free Tier, in-use external IP addresses are available without additional cost until you have used a number of hours equal to the total hours in the current month. GCP Free Tier for in-use external IP addresses applies to all instance types, not just f1-micro instances.

Comment: @TravisWebb absolutely right -- that's why I mentioned IP addresses in 2020 in the answer :)

Comment: GKE no longer supports `f1-micro` instances so there's is no way to have a free Kubernetes cluster on GCP as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Olshansk thanks for your update, I've modified the answer slightly to account for the change.

Comment: @robsiemb Hi, Can we use balanced persistent disks as well to be eligible for always free? Their price is actually more than standard ones but less than SSDs,

Comment: @MayankSinghal I'm not certain, but I woudln't expect so, as the always free tier explicitly calls out 30GB/month per month of HDD only.